# find and replace with Linux command

Tags: linux, replace, find

I have a huge SQL file that I want to replace numbers between ( and , characters with '' by Linux commands.for example I have:

```
(10638,455375,0,0,'98307350','2016-11-05 18:05:46'),
(10639,183500,0,0,'98307350','2016-11-05 18:05:46')
```

I want to change it to:

```
('',455375,0,0,'98307350','2016-11-05 18:05:46'),
('',183500,0,0,'98307350','2016-11-05 18:05:46')
```

How can I do so?

Answer (score 1):

Use the `sed` command:

```
cat example.sql | sed "s/([^,]*/(''/"
```

Comment: thanks a lot my friend but it just works for first one not all of the occurrences. I changed it to cat example.sql | sed "s/([^,]*/(''/g"

Comment: Are there newline characters like in your example? In my case it's working like a charm for every of the two lines of your sample input.

Comment: No there is not newline. cat example.sql | sed "s/([^,]*/(''/g" works fine.you saved my life :)

Comment: Strange. In my case there's no difference in the output lines...But you're welcome ;)